# Show that there are only four solution to $P(x^2)\equiv -1\pmod{x}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, analytic-number-theory

The function $P(n)$ gives the smallest prime larger or equal to n. Example: $P(3)=3,P(4)=5.$

Show that, Equation $P(x^2)\equiv -1\pmod{x}$ have only four solution such as $x=1,2,3,5$? Where $x\in\mathbb{Z}_+$.

Source code Pari GP

```
? for(a=1,10000,if(nextprime(a^2)%a==a-1, print ([a])))
[1]
[2]
[3]
[5]
```

Comment: I would expect that this can't be proven.   It would follow from the (plausible) conjecture that there is always a prime between $n^2$ and $n^2+n$  (excluding a few small counterexamples), but again we really don't know how to prove statements like that.  After all, the (much weaker) Legendre conjecture (that there is always at least one prime between $n^2$ and $(n+1)^2$) remains open.

Comment: @lulu Just as an illustration how close (and yet how far) to that sufficient condition we are:  We *do* have a prime between $n^2-n^{1.05}$ and $n^2$ for $n\gg 0$ [Baker, Harman and Pintz](https://doi.org/10.1112%2Fplms%2F83.3.532)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen  Oh, thank you.  I wasn't sure how close/far current knowledge was.

Comment: Note:  The $n^2, n^2+n$ conjecture wouldn't quite be enough, as we could still have $n^2+n-1$ as the least prime greater than $n^2$.  Accordingly, you'd need something just a hair stronger.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen let function $Pr(n)$ gives greatest prime $p\le n$ (ex. $Pr(6)=5$) so from your comment, can we conclude, $Pr(x^2)\equiv 1\pmod{x}$ have finite solution$(x=2,3,4,6)$?